# how does IE or chrome verifies certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates

If the HTTPS webserver uses self signed certificate, the web browser
warns the user as follow.

http://www.sslshopper.com/assets/images/iis7/iis7-self-signed-certificate-8-certificate-not-trusted.png

I am curious how can browser tell if the certificate is self signed or not(in detail).
is there any technically detailed document which describes this process?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the complete detail in  [RFC5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246).

Put very simple: Every certificate should be signed by a third party. Each third party's certificates are included within your browser. The browser can check if the certificate is signed by a third party it trusts, if it's signed by the same server of which you are demanding to see the identity, then it's considered self signed.